# Documentation or examples for ''newSession'' and 'resumeSession' events in TLS module for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I am having a hard time finding documentation and examples for the 'newSession' and 'resumeSession' events for the TLS module in node.js.
Any links or help in this direction is appreciated. I need to know more about these events in order to implement a fault resistant tls connection in node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy: [Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_event_newsession).

`sessionData` is a simple object, which you could `JSON.stringify(sessionData)` and save in a Redis Database. Later on, you can `JSON.parse(sessionData)` it again and resume the session.

The server itself only needs the session ID (that is sent by the client) to find its session data (if available). If the server can't find the corresponding session data to a session ID, it will start a new session.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var tls = require("tls");

/**
 * Initialize a new TLS server.
 */
var opts = {
      cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem")
    , key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/key.pem")
    }
  , server = tls.createServer(opts).listen(443);

/**
 * TLS session management.
 */
var sessions = {};

server.on("newSession", function(sessionId, sessionData) {
  sessions[sessionId.toString("hex")] = sessionData;
});
server.on("resumeSession", function(sessionId, callback) {
  sessionId = sessionId.toString("hex");
  if(sessionId in sessions)
    callback(null, sessions[sessionId]); // resume an existing session
  else
    callback(null, null); // new session will be started

  // you could also emit an error, which wil terminate the connection
  // callback(new Error("lol wut"));
});

/**
 * Request handler.
 */
server.on("request", function(req, res) {
  res.end("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: so say...i somehow sent this hex representation of the session id at the client end...how do i use it at the client end for resuming the session?...using the hex representation for the sessionidContext option doesn't help..or in general how to specify the sessionid while connecting to resume a session on a tls enabled communication(assuming the the server end uses the above code implementation)....

Comment: You asked for an example for the server-side events `newSession` and `resumeSession`. I provided you with a working code example of the server-side implementation, hence I ask you to accept this as an answer.

The client-side is a whole lot different thing, to which I also replied to [another question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18048301/420747).