# Type of session id returned by newSession event of tls module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

When using console.log() in node to output the sessionid returned by tls's [newSession](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_event_newsession) event, it output the sessionid in the following format -

```
     <SlowBuffer fa de 06 ab 51 d6 30 1b e8 ad 09 14 0e c1 1e eb 56 53 ee 6d b5 ef 9d 99  5d 1a eb 79 dc aa 34 3a>
```

What format is this? And in what format should I save it to retreive it later?

Comment: It is a buffer. To get the readable value, do a.toString(), where a is your buffer.

Comment: It's giving some garbled text.

Comment: Session id is a unique identifier, so it is not supposed to be plain text. Can you post it ?

Comment: Well, I expected something like - 8B08B7B69F6DC47ADE2C49FAEB9CA9EB44DBC01856CE2F15859B916CCAE7A3CE ..which is the sessionid output of openssl's sclient.. what i am really getting is some garbled text.. tried toString('utf-8'),toString('ascii') etc.. but still result is the same..

Comment: [The docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer). Do you even read them? OpenSSL is giving you the hexadecimal equivalent of the binary data. Node supports this with `buffer.toString("hex")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [already shown in one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18048169/420747), just use `sessionId.toString("hex")`.

As per the TLS RFC the session ID is a random byte sequence, you can't expect it to be text with some sort of meaning.